# Jackson Bi-directional Serialization with linking object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to properly serialize an object that is available to two objects as well as its own object. I want to be able to look at site admins, as well as sites a user is admin of, and the admins of a particular site. I have tried using @JSONbackmanaged and it simply only gave IDs. Is something like this possible? This is psuedocode so there are possible syntax errors but it is as close to possible. Hibernate is managing the ORM and loading of these pojos.

```
public class SiteAdmin {

     private Integer id;
     private Site site;
     private User user;

     @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
     public Facility getSite() {
        return this.sitey;
     }

     public void setSite(Site site) {
         this.site = site;
     }

     @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
     public User getUser() {
         return this.user;
     }

     public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
     }
}
```

and in user.java I have

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public Set<SiteAdmin> getSiteAdmins() {
    return this.siteAdmins;
}
```

and in site.java I have

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public Set<SiteAdmin> getSiteAdmins() {
    return this.siteAdmins;
}
```

What I am looking for when I serialize is something like this

for User:

```
{
   id: 2
   name: 'foo',
   siteAdmin: {
       user: 2,
       site: { id: 6, name: 'site' }
   }
}
```

For site

```
{
   id: 6
   name: 'site',
   siteAdmins: [
      {
        user: {id : 2, name: 'foo'},
        site: 6 
      },
      {
        user: {id : 3, name: 'bar'},
        site: 6 
      },
   ]
}
```

Instead I am getting something like this

```
{
   id: 6
   name: "site",
   siteAdmins: [
      {
        site: {
           id: 6
           name: "site",
           siteAdmins: [ 
             site: 6,
             user: {id : 2, name: "foo"}
           ]
         },
         user: {id : 3, name: "bar"}
       }, 
       1
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using @JsonIgnoreProperties instead of @JsonIdentityInfo. It will ignore child properties on the set. ex.

In site.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"site"})
public Set<SiteAdmin> getSiteAdmins() {
    return this.siteAdmins;
}
```

In user.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"user"})
public Set<SiteAdmin> getSiteAdmins() {
    return this.siteAdmins;
}
```